# download SQL Developer from Oracle automatically using bash wget Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: bash, oracle-sqldeveloper, wget, ubuntu-20.04

This is the code:

```
wget --http-user=MyUsr --http-password=MyPwd 'https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper-20.4.1.407.0006-no-jre.zip'
```

But it doesn't work.
How can I download the file by logging in automatically and accepting the license automatically?
I also tried:

```
wget --ftp-user=MyUsr --ftp-password=MyPwd 'https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper-20.4.1.407.0006-no-jre.zip'
```

,

```
wget --http-user='MyUsr' --http-password='MyPwd' 'https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper-20.4.1.407.0006-no-jre.zip'
```

,

```
wget -c --no-cookies --no-check-certificate --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" --http-user=MyUsr --http-password=MyPwd 'https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper-20.4.1.407.0006-no-jre.zip'
```

but without success.

UPDATE:

Also this:

```
wget --post-data 'user=MyUsr&passwrd=MyPwd' 'https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper-20.4.1.407.0006-no-jre.zip'
```

And this:

```
wget -c --no-cookies --no-check-certificate --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" --post-data 'user=MyUsr&passwrd=MyPwd' 'https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper-20.4.1.407.0006-no-jre.zip'
```

I'm trying haphazardly, I don't know how to do it.

Comment: This is basically asking someone to reverse-engineer how Oracle does access control for you -- which is able to change at any time, and so not particularly well-suited to be a FAQ entry.

Comment: Oracle have purposely made this challenging for licensing reasons.  Probably best to download this once to your app server - and write a script to transfer / install to your several nodes from the master.  At least then you will have tighter control of when to deploy the "latest" version - afterall - releases do get made that often bring faults which are often better avoided especially in a critical production environment